# Javascript function evaluating all if-statements before onClick event occurs

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Before dwelling into the question, please take a look at the following code snippets:

**Homepage1.jsp contains buttons and a script:**

```
        <div>
        <button id="admin" style="float: left;" onclick="getUserID(this.id)"><b>Admin</b></button>
        <button id = "chef" style="float: left;" onclick="getUserID(this.id)"><b>Chef</b></button>
        <button id = "user" style="float: left;" onclick="getUserID(this.id)"><b>User</b></button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getUserID(clicked_id) {

    if (clicked_id == "admin") {
        <%session.setAttribute("userID", "admin");%>
    }
    else if (clicked_id == "chef") {
        <%session.setAttribute("userID", "chef");%>
    }
    else if (clicked_id == "user") {
        <%session.setAttribute("userID", "user");%>
    }

    window.location = "/Homepage2.jsp";
}
```

**Homepage2.jsp contains:**

```
<%Object userName = session.getAttribute("userID");%>
```

My problem is that regardless of which of the three buttons I click (admin, chef, or user), the next jsp file (Homepage2.jsp) always gets the information relating to the "user".

What I noticed after debugging this code is that every if statement is being evaluated in the function getUserID(clicked_id) so that the last if statement overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: Your JSP code runs on the server *before* the page gets to the browser, so it can't be run conditionally based on client-side JavaScript `if` statements.

Comment: you need to understand that loading a webpage is not a two-way operation ... server sends (processed) page to browser - end communcation

Comment: if you want to set the session, you probably need to send a request to do that

Comment: server is `java` - so it may be relevant @ajb

Comment: @JaromandaX And it's probably running on an operating system written in C++, does that make C++ relevant?  The server code isn't part of the question here.

Comment: Server code is executed before Browser Code. You can't use Client Side JavaScript to create Server Code. Send AJAX to the Server, if you want the Client to generate Server results.

Comment: I said **may** @ajb - and you forgot to get down to `assembler` and `microcode` in your sarcastic reply :p